# Nested Relationship Serializer Rest Framework Not Displaying Properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to display the attributes in the Disease Model and Evidence Model, but the attributes that is displayed on the end link are only those attributes that are present in the Rule Model.

Models.py :-

```
class Rule(models.Model):

    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, default=0,related_name="DRules")

    evidence = models.ForeignKey(Evidence, default=0,related_name="ERules")

    measure_of_belief = models.PositiveIntegerField( \
        help_text="The measure of belief (percentage) that a disease is present given this evidence exists", \
        default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])

    measure_of_disbelief = models.PositiveIntegerField( \
        help_text="The measure of disbelief (percentage) that a disease is present given an evidence does not exists", \
        default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])

    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
           return "{}-{}".format(self.disease, self.evidence)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Rule"
        verbose_name_plural = "Rules"
        unique_together = ('disease', 'evidence',)


class Disease(models.Model):
    """
        The model where the category will be stored
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    advise = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Disease"
        verbose_name_plural = "Diseases"

class Evidence(models.Model):


    evidence_choices = {
        ("Observable Evidence", ("Observable Evidence")),
        ("Cause", ("Cause"))
    }

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    evidence_type = models.CharField(choices = evidence_choices,max_length=20,default="Observable Evidences")
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image_name = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', default='media/None/no-img.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Evidence"
        verbose_name_plural = "Evidences"
```

Serializers.py

```
class DiseaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = '__all__'

class EvidenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Evidence
        fields = '__all__'

class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    DRules = DiseaseSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    ERules = EvidenceSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Rule 
        fields = ('measure_of_belief','disease','evidence','DRules','ERules')
```

views.py:-

```
class ShowDiseaseProfile(APIView):

    def get(self,request,profileid):


        profile = Rule.objects.filter(
            disease_id=profileid)

        serializer = RuleSerializer(
            profile,many=True)


        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display all data that is present on the disease, evidence, and rule.

There is no error or crashing, the value from the disease model and evidence model is just not displaying.

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIygT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: previous answer was incorrect. Updated the answer.

You are using incorrect field names in your serializer. Below is the correct one:

```
class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    disease = DiseaseSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    evidence = EvidenceSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Rule 
        fields = ('measure_of_belief','disease','evidence','DRules','ERules')
```

related_name param on the foreign key field is used for reverse lookups. Checkout the docs for a proper explanation. For example:

```
disease = Disease.objects.get(id=200)
d_rules = disease.DRules.all()
```

Use select_related query to optimize the sql query. Select related uses a join to fetch the data in one sql operation.

```
class ShowDiseaseProfile(APIView):

    def get(self,request,profileid):


        profile = (Rule.objects.filter(disease_id=profileid)
                   .select_related('disease', 'evidence'))

        serializer = RuleSerializer(
            profile,many=True)


        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I got the error "Cannot find 'DRules' on Rule object, 'DRules' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()", so I tried to scour the internet and I think the problem is that I have a 1.10 version of Django

Comment: Should I update my Django or not because there might be deprecated values?

Comment: what's the issue you found regarding this problem and django 1.10?

Comment: @KyleSun: I have updated the answer. Previous answer was incorrect.